# How to save the x and y of iframe (scrollto)? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

After looking for several hours and not finding an answer either way I decided to come to you, oh great community of people who I always look to for help.  I have an iframe that when scrolled by my user, they leave, then come back, we'd like to use scrollto to bring back to the right position.  So how can I save/export/add to variable the x and y of this iframe or is that impossible?

Comment: Do you have access to the page inside the `iframe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the x,y variables to cookie using this jquery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Example:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    //save scroll on unload
    $.cookie('scroll_x',$("#yourElementId").scrollLeft());
    $.cookie('scroll_y',$("#yourElementId").scrollTop());
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    //restore scroll when the dom is ready
    var x = $.cookie('scroll_x');
    var y = $.cookie('scroll_y');
    if( x != null ) $("#yourElementId").scrollLeft(x);
    if( y != null ) $("#yourElementId").scrollTop(y);
});
```

Where the id of your element your want to scroll is "yourElementId".

Answer (score 0):

The first step you need to take is getting the x/y components. You can achieve this by using `elem.scrollTop` and `elem.scrollLeft`. Record these to a local storage, detecting scroll using the `onscroll` event. Then, the next page load, assign the recorded x/y compontents to the `elem.scrolLTop` and `elem.scrollLeft` of the iframe.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

frame.contentWindow.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("coordinates", this.scrollLeft + "," + this.scrollTop);
}, false);

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("coordinates")){
        var coordinates = sessionStorage.getItem("coordinate").split(",");
        frame.scrollLeft = coordinates[0];
        frame.scrollTop = coordinates[1];
    }
}, false);
```

Note: untested and most likely guaranteed not to work without modifications to clean through errors.

**Edit: I realized that the iframe doesn't handle `onscroll`, so you'd have to find a workaround for that...**

Comment: I think it should be `frame.contentWindow.addEventListener("scroll", ...`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/olonoh/1/edit (enable jsbin "console" tab, the "run with js" on the output panel)

Comment: hmm... you're right. but http://jsfiddle.net/fwSgt/ doesn't work. It did when I applied the concept to a div though.

Comment: I tried jsfiddle too. Here is why it doesn't work: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://forrst.com/posts from frame with URL http://fiddle.jshell.net/fwSgt/show/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.` Both documents must be in the same domain.